# how to connect a printer to a Tablet without a bluetooth connection?

Tags: android, printers

I want to print a statement document or cibil report on click of print command in my app. Printer is not connected via bluetooth. What are the ways to achieve this. How to start? Can i use PrinterManager and PrinterAdapter and send printjob (jobname and adapter)? Please guide me. Thank you.

Comment: Can you use PrintHelper?

Comment: See this project  https://github.com/SureshCS-50/Android-wifi-print

Comment: I haven't tried with PrintHelper. But i have used PrintManager.

Comment: I tried with PrintHelper for print bitmap image and it will work fine for me if u want to print bitmap image then tell me i will share my code here...

Comment: @Nikunj m looking for some sdk if possible. this is the printer- Epson L130 Ink-Tank Printer. This i search but it is only fr TM series in EPSON- https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=5669&scat=61&pcat=52